omnipay/stripe use tokens instead of raw card data
I have a file hosting site. It currently uses stripe payment gateway created by omnipay.
When a user attempts to upgrade it returns a message saying there has been an error because my website is sending raw card data instead of token to stripe. Ive looked at alot of my code and read alot of documentationI just cant work this out. Im sure I can include the stripe.js in my footer So I have done```
that.
I will copy and paste a file that talk about turning the card number into a token . it doesnt seem to be working
Any help would be greatly appreciated
<?php

/**
 * Stripe Charge Gateway.
 */
namespace Omnipay\Stripe;

/**
 * Stripe Charge Gateway.
 *
 * @see \Omnipay\Stripe\AbstractGateway
 * @see \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\AbstractRequest
 *
 * @link https://stripe.com/docs/api
 *
 */
class Gateway extends AbstractGateway
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Stripe Charge';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\AuthorizeRequest
     */
    public function authorize(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\AuthorizeRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CaptureRequest
     */
    public function capture(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CaptureRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\PurchaseRequest
     */
    public function purchase(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\PurchaseRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated 2.3.3:3.0.0 duplicate of \Omnipay\Stripe\Gateway::fetchTransaction()
     * @see \Omnipay\Stripe\Gateway::fetchTransaction()
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchChargeRequest
     */
    public function fetchCharge(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchChargeRequest', $parameters);
    }

    //
    // Cards
    // @link https://stripe.com/docs/api#cards
    //

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateCardRequest
     */
    public function createCard(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateCardRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\UpdateCardRequest
     */
    public function updateCard(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\UpdateCardRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeleteCardRequest
     */
    public function deleteCard(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeleteCardRequest', $parameters);
    }

    //
    // Tokens
    // @link https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens
    //

    /**
     * Creates a single use token that wraps the details of a credit card.
     * This token can be used in place of a credit card associative array with any API method.
     * These tokens can only be used once: by creating a new charge object, or attaching them to a customer.
     *
     * This kind of token is also useful when sharing clients between one platform and a connect account.
     * Use this request to create a new token to make a direct charge on a customer of the platform.
     *
     * @param array $parameters parameters to be passed in to the TokenRequest.
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateTokenRequest The create token request.
     */
    public function createToken(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateTokenRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Stripe Fetch Token Request.
     *
     * Often you want to be able to charge credit cards or send payments
     * to bank accounts without having to hold sensitive card information
     * on your own servers. Stripe.js makes this easy in the browser, but
     * you can use the same technique in other environments with our token API.
     *
     * Tokens can be created with your publishable API key, which can safely
     * be embedded in downloadable applications like iPhone and Android apps.
     * You can then use a token anywhere in our API that a card or bank account
     * is accepted. Note that tokens are not meant to be stored or used more
     * than once—to store these details for use later, you should create
     * Customer or Recipient objects.
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchTokenRequest
     */
    public function fetchToken(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchTokenRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Create Plan
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreatePlanRequest
     */
    public function createPlan(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreatePlanRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Plan
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchPlanRequest
     */
    public function fetchPlan(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchPlanRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Delete Plan
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeletePlanRequest
     */
    public function deletePlan(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeletePlanRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * List Plans
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\ListPlansRequest
     */
    public function listPlans(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\ListPlansRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Create Subscription
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateSubscriptionRequest
     */
    public function createSubscription(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateSubscriptionRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Subscription
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSubscriptionRequest
     */
    public function fetchSubscription(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSubscriptionRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Update Subscription
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\UpdateSubscriptionRequest
     */
    public function updateSubscription(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\UpdateSubscriptionRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel Subscription
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CancelSubscriptionRequest
     */
    public function cancelSubscription(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CancelSubscriptionRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Schedule Subscription
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSubscriptionSchedulesRequest
     */
    public function fetchSubscriptionSchedules(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSubscriptionSchedulesRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Event
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchEventRequest
     */
    public function fetchEvent(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchEventRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Invoice Lines
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceLinesRequest
     */
    public function fetchInvoiceLines(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceLinesRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Invoice
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceRequest
     */
    public function fetchInvoice(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * List Invoices
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\ListInvoicesRequest
     */
    public function listInvoices(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\ListInvoicesRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Create Invoice Item
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateInvoiceItemRequest
     */
    public function createInvoiceItem(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateInvoiceItemRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Invoice Item
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceItemRequest
     */
    public function fetchInvoiceItem(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchInvoiceItemRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Delete Invoice Item
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeleteInvoiceItemRequest
     */
    public function deleteInvoiceItem(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeleteInvoiceItemRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateSourceRequest
     */
    public function createSource(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateSourceRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\AttachSourceRequest
     */
    public function attachSource(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\AttachSourceRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSourceRequest
     */
    public function detachSource(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DetachSourceRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSourceRequest
     */
    public function fetchSource(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchSourceRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Create a completePurchase request.
     *
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return \Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CompletePurchaseRequest
     */
    public function completePurchase(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CompletePurchaseRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest
     */
    public function createCoupon(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\CreateCouponRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest
     */
    public function fetchCoupon(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\FetchCouponRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest
     */
    public function deleteCoupon(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\DeleteCouponRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest
     */
    public function updateCoupon(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\UpdateCouponRequest', $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     *
     * @return \Omnipay\Common\Message\AbstractRequest
     */
    public function listCoupons(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Omnipay\Stripe\Message\ListCouponsRequest', $parameters);
    }
}


Ive tried using ai to help me , read alot of documentation on stripe, read alot of the code on my site

"it returns a message saying there has been an error because my website is sending raw card data instead of token to stripe." This message should be included here. My guess is it's the same message as this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78565265/sending-credit-card-numbers-directly-to-the-stripe-api-is-generally-unsafe And about a million other threads on StackOverflow about this error message.
